# Need help compiling this iteration and interface program

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write this java program for a user to input two rational numbers and ask from a menu of options to compute some sort of function A. I'm stuck in a few places and don't know what else to do. I need some guidance. it wont compile. says constructor Rational is undefined and the last default is an invalid label  .it is two class files were the driver files uses the rational file. both files are uploaded and separated by text. need help

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.*; 

 public class RationalDriver{
 public static void main(String[] args){

 int rationalNum1, rationalDen1, rationalNum2, rationalDen2;

 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
 // first rational 
 System.out.println(" Input first rational number for the Numerator");
 rationalNum1 = in.nextInt();
 System.out.println(" Input first rational number for the Denominator");
 rationalDen1 = in.nextInt();
 if (rationalDen1 == 0){
 System.out.println(" Cannont divide by zero ");
 System.out.println(" please re enter another number ");
 }
 System.out.println("Rational Number #1 = ("+rationalNum1+"/"+rationalDen1+")");          
//Displays 1st Rational Number

// second rational
System.out.println(" Input 2nd rational number for the 2nd Numerator");
rationalNum2 = in.nextInt();
System.out.println(" Input 2nd rational number for the 2nd Denominator");
rationalDen2 = in.nextInt();
if (rationalDen2 == 0){
System.out.println("Cannont divide by zero");
System.out.println(" please re enter another number");
}
System.out.println("Rational Number #2 = ("+rationalNum2+"/"+rationalDen2+")");  
 //Displays 2nd Rational Number

 Rational r1 = new Rational ( rationalNum1, rationalDen1);
 Rational r2 = new Rational ( rationalNum2, rationalDen2);

     // System.out.println;//toString
   }


 public void display_menu() //menu options 
 {
 System.out.print(" Enter the corresponding number for the desired action ");
 System.out.println("1) Addition\n2) 2) Subtraction\n3) 3) Multiplication\n4)    4)Division\n5) 5) Test for Eqaulity\n6) 6) Change 1st rational number\n7) 7) Change 2nd rational number"); 
}    
public void question()
{
 System.out.println("Do you want to exit? [y/n]");  // ask user if they want to quit   with yes or no option
Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);
switch (q.nextInt()) 
 {
 case 'y' :
 System.out.println ("Thank you and goodbye.");
 break;

 case 'n' :
 InputMenu();
 break;
 default:

 System.err.println ( "Unrecognized option" );
 break;
 }
}
public void InputMenu()  // keys for the menu
{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
display_menu();
switch (in.nextInt()) 
{
 case 1: //addition
 System.out.println ( "1" );
 System.out.println( "("+rationalNum1+"/"+rationalDen1+")"+ " + " + " ("+rationalNum2+"/"+rationalDen2+")" + "=" +  r1.add(r2));   
 break;

 case 2: //subtraction
 System.out.println ( "2" );
 System.out.println( "("+rationalNum1+"/"+rationalDen1+")"+ " - " + "("+rationalNum2+"/"+rationalDen2+")" + "=" +  r1.subtract(r2));   
 break;

 case 3: //mulitplication 
 System.out.println ( "3" );
 System.out.println( "("+rationalNum1+"/"+rationalDen1+")"+ " * " + "      ("+rationalNum2+"/"+rationalDen2+")" + "=" +  r1.multiply(r2));    
 break;

 case 4: //division
 System.out.println ( "4" );
 System.out.println( "("+rationalNum1+"/"+rationalDen1+")"+ " / " + "("+rationalNum2+"/"+rationalDen2+")" + "=" +  r1.divide(r2));      
 break;

 case 5: //compare to
 System.out.println ( "5" );
 question();
 break;

 case 6: //change the 1st Rational Number
 System.out.println ( "6" );
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
 System.out.println(" Input first rational number for the Numerator");
 rationalNum1 = in.nextInt();
 System.out.println(" Input first rational number for the Denominator");
 rationalDen1 = in.nextInt();
 if (rationalDen1 == 0){
 System.out.println(" Cannont divide by zero");
 System.out.println(" please re enter another number");
 }
 break;

 case 7: //change the 2nd Rational Number
 System.out.println ( "7" );
 System.out.println(" Input 2nd rational number for the 2nd Numerator");
 rationalNum2 = in.nextInt();
 System.out.println(" Input 2nd rational number for the 2nd Denominator");
 rationalDen2 = in.nextInt();
 if (rationalDen2 == 0){
 System.out.println("Cannont divide by zero");
 System.out.println(" please re enter another number");
 break;


 default:
 System.err.println ( "Unrecognized option" );
 break;
}
}
}
}
```

Here is the class file for rational

```
public class Rational{

 private int Numerator;
 private int Denominator;


 //constructors
 public Rational(){  
 Numerator = 1;
 Denominator = 1 ;

 }

//setters 
//a-numerator
//b-denmonator 
 //c other.getNumerator
 //d-other.getDenominator
   public void add (Rational other){                    // (ad + bc) / bd                          
   Numerator = (Numerator*other.getDenominator() + Denominator*other.getNumerator());
   Denominator = (Denominator*other.getDenominator());
  //Normalize();
   }
   public void subtract (Rational other){               // (ad-bc) / bd
   Numerator = (Numerator*other.getDenominator() - Denominator*other.getNumerator());
   Denominator = (Denominator*other.getDenominator());
   //Normalize();
   } 
  public void multiply (Rational other){                   // ac/db
  Numerator = (Numerator*other.getNumerator() / other.getDenominator()* Denominator);
  // Normalize();
  }
 public void divide (Rational other){// 
 }

  public int getNumerator(){
  return Numerator;
  }

  public int getDenominator(){
  return Denominator;
  }

 //toString    
 //public String toString(){
 //return toString()+ (rationalNum1 + "/" +  rationalDen1);
 }
```

Comment: Don't upload code and expect people to read it and try to deduce what you're stuck on. Tell us the specific problem you're having.

Comment: @BobbyDigital it wont compile. says constructor Rational is undefined and the last default is an invalid label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main class you have:

```
Rational r1 = new Rational ( rationalNum1, rationalDen1);
Rational r2 = new Rational ( rationalNum2, rationalDen2);
```

you are passing 2 integers to a constructer that recives void, so you have to change your constructer (of Rational class) like this:

```
 public Rational(int rationalNumber, int rationalDen){  
 Numerator = rationalNumber;
 Denominator = rationalDen;

 }
```

Hope it helps, let me know if it worked or if there is more something wrong...

Edit: your Scanner and print error.
You have this:

```
public void question()
{
 System.out.println("Do you want to exit? [y/n]");  // ask user if they want to quit   with yes or no option
 Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);
 switch (q.nextInt()) // here you are assuming that you are reading a int in step 
 {                    // of a string
 case 'y' : // ' ' arent used for strings...
 System.out.println ("Thank you and goodbye.");
 break;

 case 'n' :
 InputMenu();
 break;
 default:

 System.err.println ( "Unrecognized option" );
 break;
 }
}
```

so, what you need is:

```
 public void question()
{
 System.out.println("Do you want to exit? [y/n]");  // ask user if they want to quit   with yes or no option
 Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);
 switch (q.nextLine()) // change nextInt to nextLine, that is the string method 
 {                    // of a string
 case "y" : //change ' ' to " "
 System.out.println ("Thank you and goodbye.");
 break;

 case "n" :  //change ' ' to " "
 InputMenu();
 break;
 default:

 System.err.println ( "Unrecognized option" );
 break;
 }
}
```

Hope it help :)

Edit 3:

in your code you have: ` 
     public class RationalDriver{
     public static void main(String[] args){

```
 int rationalNum1, rationalDen1, rationalNum2, rationalDen2; // this are local variables, they only exist inside main method
...`
}
```

So, what you can do is:

```
 public class RationalDriver{
 private static int rationalNum1, rationalDen1, rationalNum2, rationalDen2;
 public static void main(String[] args){
  // your main
 }
```

what i did was take your local variables that **only exists** in your main and turn them in global variables so when you want change their value or give them a value you just do:

```
rationalNum1 = your valor;
```

Please note that if you use any variable without initialize it with a value you will get a null point exception...

Comment: It worked perfect, last thing is I have a problem with this                     default:
     System.err.println ( "Unrecognized option" );
     break;
    }

Comment: that somewhat helped but my issue now is that is says all my rationalNum1 rationalDen1 etc etc under the case blocks cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: i have added a new piece of code, just move your **int rationalNum1, rationalDen1, rationalNum2, rationalDen2;** from main() to where i place them, that should work... if you have more problems let me know, i may be able to answer only tomorrow but i will answer it :) Good Luck

Comment: what would I set  rationalNum1 = your value;  as. I'm using the users input at the value

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a constructor `Rational (int rationalNum1, int rationalDen1){}`

In your program you used the constructor `Rational ( rationalNum1, rationalDen1)`
when you have only declared the default constructor `public Rational()`, which does no accept any arguments.

It is possible to have multiple constructor for a class and they are differentiated by the type and number of argument they accept.

E.g

```
class A(int a, int b);
```

is same as

```
Class A(int c, int b);
```

but not

```
Class(int a, float d)
```